# Monadic composition exercise wrong

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, chain

### Background

I am reading the Mostly [Adequate Guide to Functional Programming](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide) and making all the exercises. I am in chapter 9, *Monadic Onions* but I am struggling with the exercises.

### Exercise 1

> Considering a User object as follow, use `safeProp` and `map/join` or `chain` to safely get the street name when given a user:
>
> ```
> // safeProp :: String -> Object -> Maybe a
> const safeProp = curry((p, obj) => compose(Maybe.of, prop(p))(obj));
>
> const user = {  
>   id: 1,  
>   name: 'Albert',  
>   address: {  
>     street: {  
>       number: 22,  
>       name: 'Walnut St',  
>     },  
>   },  
> };
> ```

### Solution 1

```
// getStreetName :: User -> Maybe String
const getStreetName = compose(
    chain( safeProp( "name" ) ),
    chain( safeProp( "street" ) ),
    safeProp( "address" )    
);
```

This one was easy. `safeProp` returns a Maybe Monad. So, when composing `safeProp`, we need to use `chain` ( aka `flatMap` ) to follow up, othwerwise instead of getting a `Maybe.of("value")` we will end up with `Maybe.of( Maybe.of("value") )`.

**Rule inferred**: if you want to compose function A and function B, and both return Monads, use `chain`!

### Exercise 2

> Given the following functions,  use getFile to get the filepath, remove the directory and keep only the basename, then purely log it. Hint: you may want to use `split` and `last` to obtain the basename from a filepath.
>
> ```
> // getFile :: () -> IO String
> const getFile = () => IO.of('/home/mostly-adequate/ch9.md');
>
> // pureLog :: String -> IO ()
> const pureLog = str => new IO(() => console.log(str));
> ```

### Solution 2

```
const getBaseName = compose( last, split("/") );

const logFilename = compose(
    chain( pureLog ),
    map( getBaseName ),
    getFile
);
```

This one is a bit more tricky, but I also managed it.

So, `getFile` returns an IO Monad. But `getBaseMap` returns only a string.
So, I have function A which returns a Monad, and function B, which returns a primitive type. I can't compose them using `chain` because function B has nothing that needs to be flatten. This means I need `map` to compose A with B!

**Yet another rule!**

Now, I need to compose B with pureLog ( C ).
After apllying map on B, it will return the IO Monad with the transformed value. Lets call this MB. Given that I need to compose MB with C (which returns a monad) I cann apply rule 1 and simply use `chain`.

Phew !

Let's go to the last one!

### Exercise 3:

> Given the following functions,  use `validateEmail`, `addToMailingList` and `emailBlast` to create a function which adds a new email to the mailing list if valid, and then notify the whole list.
>
> // validateEmail :: Email -> Either String Email
>   // addToMailingList :: Email -> IO([Email])
>   // emailBlast :: [Email] -> IO ()

### Solution 3?

I have no idea on how to make this one ....

This is what I did so far:

```
// joinMailingList :: Email -> Either String (IO ())
const joinMailingList = compose(
    chain( emailBlast ),
    chain( addToMailingList ),
    validateEmail    
);
```

But this is wrong. I get the follwing error:

> The function has an invalid type; hint: `joinMailingList` should return an Either String (IO ())

Questions:

1. How can I fix this? Can someone explain me what is wrong?
2. Should I have inferred additional rules from the previous exercises ( am I missing some composability rule here ) ?

Comment: If you downvote, explain why

Comment: Can you reduce this to just the relevant info?  I had to scroll past two screenfuls of stuff before getting to your actual question/problem.

Comment: Your 1st rule isn't quite correct: If you want to compose actions (functions returning a monad) you need kleisli composition. `chain` is meant for chaining an effect (the result of a monadic computation) with another action.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No I can't because the whole thing ties to my second question. This is not just about finding out what's wrong, it's also about finding out what knowledge I missed in order to get it wrong the first time.

Comment: @ftor I didn't study kleisi composition yet, I believe that may be in the following chapters. I am still learning after all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // validateEmail :: Email -> Either String Email
> // addToMailingList :: Email -> IO([Email])
> // emailBlast :: [Email] -> IO ()
> ```

mean that you can't use `Either.chain`, you have to **`map`** over the `Either String` that the first function in the composition (`validateEmail`) returns. As you know, "*I can't compose them using chain because function B has nothing that needs to be flatten.*".

Notice also that we have *two* monads here, two *different* monads: `Either` and `IO`. `chain` doesn't work on *any* monad, it only works on the *same* monadic type in both of its arguments. Every monad (i.e. every type that is a monad) has its own `chain` method. Using a single `chain` function is just an abstraction which makes use of runtime polymorphism (or compile time polymorphism if the language has a compiler supporting that). So we will need

```
function joinMailingList(email) {
    return Either.map(validateEmail(email), addAndBlast)
}
function addAndBlast(email) {
    return IO.chain(addToMailingList(email), emailBlast)
}
```

Comment: [`compose`](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/appendix_a.html#compose) seems to express left-to-right composition, though.

Comment: @ftor You mean that's the actual mistake? Maybe, I don't think it's important, that's rather trivial to resolve.